# Bash sed replace everything in a textfile until the apperance of the first alphabetic character

Tags: bash, loops, sed

Can anybody help me with this? I have a bunch of text-files, that I want to alter. They all start with something else but a normal alphabetical character. I now want to delete everything before the appearnace of a alphabetical character, so that they start with their title,keeping everything else following intact.

here's an example:

```
=================================================================================

TITLE OF SONG

Text text text
Text text text

ReFrain:
Text text text

written 16.08.1998
```

And I want it to look like this

```
TITLE OF SONG

Text text text
Text text text

ReFrain:
Text text text

written 16.08.1998
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
for f in *.txt; do sed 's/^.*[a-zA-Z]/^.[a-zA-Z]/g'; done
```

It is not working

I'm fairly new to this, so please bear with me.

best Stef

Comment: The only difference between your 2 files is that there is an extra `"` at the start of what you want.  Correct?  Unclear to me what you mean by your description.  The first alphabetical letter is `T` from the word `Title` right?

Comment: That is because somebody edited my post. In the first part of my example, the text started with "===================" and a few line breaks before the text. I do not know, how I can recert to my original post, neither do I know, why someone altered it. But you are right, anyway the fiorst capital letter would be the T of the word title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl is handy here:

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//s' file ...
```

The -0777 option causes perl to slurp the entire file into the default variable,
and the s/// command removes all leading non-alpha characters.

Comment: @ glenn jackmann Could you maybe tell me, how to make this loop over a bunch of textfiles? I tried ```for f in *.txt; do perl -0777 -pe -i 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//s'; done```, but that does not work.

Comment: I found it out: It's done like this: ```for f in *.txt; do perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//s' $f; done***. Thanx to everyone who has helped

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need a loop: `perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//s'  *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 'N;N;s/\("\).*\n\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/\1\2/' input_file
"TITLE OF SONG

Text text text
Text text text

ReFrain:
Text text text

written 16.08.1998"
```

or

```
$ sed ':a;N;s/\("\)[^[:alpha:]]*\n\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\2/;ba' input_file
"TITLE OF SONG

Text text text
Text text text

ReFrain:
Text text text

written 16.08.1998"
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem, sadly.In the first part of my example, the text started with "===================" and a few line breaks before the text. I wanted to get rid of those and leave the rest of the text intact. When I use your proposal, the text stays as it was.

Comment: @sw-1966 Please check additional code

Comment: sadly, this does not work either, the text stays like it was before, starting with "========"

Comment: Yet sed -i 's/^[^[:alnum:]]*//' xx02.txt works, now I just need to get rid of the linebreaks before the first character and them I'm done.

Comment: @sw-1966 Please post your sample data again exactly as it is so I can copy and paste. The second code works with any amount of characters before alphabetic characters so long as it starts with a `"` quote